# Creating an associative array from 2 inputs

Tags: shell

I have two files with the following contents:

- `beam.csv`

```
T11
G14
M10
```

- `frequency.csv`

```
115000
120000
344444
```

I want to associate each beam with a frequency i.e. build an associative array such as `NAME[beam]=frequency`

```
declare -A NAME
while read -r beam && read -r -u 3 freq; do
    NAME[$beam]=$freq
done < beam.csv 3< frequency.csv
```

But it doesn't get right at all

When I run `echo "${!NAME[@]}" "${NAME[@]}"` there is no output and when I try `echo ${NAME[T11]}`  I don't get any output as well.

Comment: Your code is working, however. Where are you executing the `echo "${!NAME[@]}" "${NAME[@]}"` command? Try adding it in the code, as the last line, and you will see the ouptut upon executing the script.

Comment: when I run my code, it's all empty, did I miss something somewhere maybe ?

Comment: Insert `declare -p BASH_SUBSHELL; break` at the beginning of the while loop.  If it prints anything other than 0, it's likely that the loop is running in a subshell different from where you `echo` the values.

Comment: **Where** are you executing the `echo`? If you have put the script in a file, and then you are executing it in `bash`, and afterwards you are executing the `echo` command, then it's normal you don't get any output, as `NAME` is the fined in the subprocess running the script, not in your shell.

Comment: I was executing the echo outside the script, but indeed inside it does report, but how am I suppose to use my array outside myscript ?

Comment: You need to execute it in your *current* shell, so `source ./myscript` not `bash ./myscript`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine. Probably you are just unaware that when you execute it like this:

```
thisisyourshellprompt$ ./yourscript
```

it actually executes in a subshell; therefore the `NAME` variable is local to that subshell where the script is run, not to the shell where you have just typed the command.

When the script is done, it returns, and you are back to your shell, where `NAME` has never been defined.

But the code works, as you can verify by putting the `echo` in the script, as in

```
declare -A NAME
while read -r beam && read -r -u 3 freq; do
    NAME[$beam]=$freq
done < beam.csv 3< frequency.csv
echo "${!NAME[@]}" "${NAME[@]}"
```

Comment: When I do create my array inside the subshell, if I want to substitute the frequency by the name from another file, all the operation has to be done from the script ?

Comment: _by the name from another file..._. I'm sorry, but I can't understand the comment.

Comment: OK let me re-phrase,my first step was to create an associative array between the name of my beam and frequency, now I have another `.csv` file where one of the column is `frequency`, I want to substitute the `frequency` by the `beam` name.

Comment: This sounds like a different question than the one in the original post. You should post a new question (and maybe accept this answer, if it solved your doubts), where you state what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: thank you Enrico for your help and clarification, indeed this deserve another question to be posted !!

Comment: A subshell, strictly, is created by a `fork()` with no `exec()`-family call; thus it inherits aliases, unexported variables, unexported functions, and the like. A shell started as an interpreter for a subprocess is outside this definition.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, could you please clarify (with your words or with a link to another Q/A) the part after the period?

Comment: `./myscript`, after forking off the subprocess, calls an equivalent to `execve("./myscript", string[]{"./myscript", NULL}, ...)`. That `execv`-family call means that the original process image is replaced with a new one. Sure, it's a shell (if the thing being exec'd has a shebang pointing at a shell interpreter), but it's a *different* shell, not a forked-off copy of the original one; that distinguishes it from conventional subshells.

Comment: ...point being that the word "subshell" has implications -- like inheriting aliases/variables/etc -- that don't apply to a shell that's started as a subprocess, so using the word "subshell" for all shells-that-are-subprocesses rather than only those that fit the narrower definition leads to confusion.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy , I'm still not completely sure I've understood. However, what you wrote sounds a bit like _all subshells are subprocesses, not all subprocesses are subshells_; therefore changing _subshell_ to _subprocess_ in my answer would fix it, am I right?